# Azure AD create user group for Application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have created a group with some users in my Azure AD.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-groups-create-azure-portal
(membership i set to assigned)

Now i want to assign these users to a application inside the AD.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-accessmanagement-group-saasapps

In the classic portal (step 4) there is only a users tab at my application not a groups and users.
In the new portal there is users and groups but the groups won't show up.

I tried this also in the

Somehow, when i use the add user/group button, i find all my users from the AD but not the group i created.

**Update:**
My APP was not created as Enterprise Apllication.Instead i created the APP just as new Application registration (Web app / API).

But it is also listed in the Enterprise Applications list

**Question:**
What could be the reason for this?

**Solution:**
It is a license problem, so we didn't get this feature at all.

Comment: Are you using the classic portal or the new one? Also a screenshot or more specific steps to reproduce this problem would be helpful.

Comment: i have updated a bit

Comment: As noted in the documentation you have **enabled Azure AD Premium or Azure AD Basic**, correct? Also, you have confirmed that your new AD Group exists in the classic portal?

Comment: i have Azure AD Basic and the group exists in both portals

Comment: Also i did not have selected Enterprise Application, i have selected App Registration (Web app / API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) with an Azure AD Premium or
>   Azure AD Basic license, you can use groups to assign access to a SaaS
>   application that's integrated with Azure AD.

As the documentation mentioned, Using Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) with an Azure AD **Premium** or Azure AD **Basic license**, you can use groups to assign access to a SaaS application that's integrated with Azure AD.

Here the screenshot about the premium Azure AD, please check it:

[image]

Comment: Also see update about my app registration, I spotted in your picture you used Enterprise App. i have selected register new App (Web app / APi)

Comment: @Gobliins when we select register new app we can use classic portal to add group,

Comment: So it's a premium feature?

Comment: No, this feature group-based access management, we can find it in Azure Active Directory `Basic`,`Premium P1`, `Premium P2`.

Comment: Yeah it seem slike we didn't have any of this licenses. That's why we can't assign groups.

Answer (score 1):

Under the Azure Active Directory editions documentation it states Group-based access management / provisioning is an Azure AD Basic feature.  [This is also covered in the Azure AD Premium P1/P2 SKU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-editions).

"Group-Based Access Management" is the feature name for having the ability to assign a group to an application.

Azure Active Directory Free is available to configure 10 applications to Azure Active Directory and assign user access based by user assignment - not group assignment.

Here is a [chart that outlines FREE, BASIC, PREMIUM P1, PREMIUM P2](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/)